# can't reset adb in eclipse , getting error

Tags: android, eclipse

I have downloaded eclipse and the android sdk tools. 
but when I create a new application, no layout file is created!
instead I'm getting some errors, among them :

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\YANIV\workspace\appcompat_v7\bin\appcompat_v7.jar'   ffffffffff      Build path  Build Path Problem

and also im unable to reset the adb (in the ddms perspective) : 
the error i get is :

[2014-12-13 01:42:53 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

[2014-12-13 01:42:54 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1

what should I do ?

Comment: is the appcompat_v7 project in the project explorer view

Comment: yes it is in the project view

Comment: is appcompat_v7.jar in the appcompat_v7 project

Comment: no. where should I see it?

Comment: `'C:\Users\YANIV\workspace\appcompat_v7\bin\appcompat_v7.jar'`

Comment: oh ok. yes it is there.

Comment: Well from what I can tell it could either be a problem with your adb or appcompat... Can you tell me how you created the project? Like new project wizard, gut, etc.

Comment: Try killing the ADB server: `ADB kill-server` then restart `ADB start-server`

Comment: tried it.. not help. anything else?